# Graph depending on a variable

Tags: pgfplots, graphs, charts

I'd like to create a graph, let's say using pgfplots, but other options are just as good if they work.

The graph is supposed to illustrate several functions. Their domain is the set of all integers greater than some fixed integer -2k. The functions are quite simple, roughly of the form f(-2k) = k, f(-2k+1)=k-1, f(-2k+2+l)=k+l (l=0 or l>0).

If I set k to be some concrete integer, e.g. k=0, plotting these functions would be quite trivial. However, I don't know how to take account of the dependency on k. In particular, I would like k to show in the axis labels - they should be of the form k-1, k, k+1, k+2 and so on.

I would really appreciate help on this!

Comment: Please, show what you try so far. Other vice this is question *do-it-for-me* which likely will not be answered.

Comment: I'm too stupid to understand fully what you meant, so  if you could show an example that would be helpful. Are you after something like `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[samples at={-5,...,5},yticklabel={$k\pgfmathprintnumber[showpos]{\tick}$}]
\addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`